# Show $f(x):=x^p$, where $p \ge 0$, is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

For p being an integer, the result follows immediately from the Algebraic Limit Theorem and Sequential Criterion. If p is not an integer, however, I cannot use these results. I have tried solving from first principles given $|x-a|<\delta$ but I can't see how to simplify $|x^p-a^p|$. Any hints?

Comment: What definition are you given for $x^p$ with $p$ non integer?

Comment: $f(x): (0 , 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: My question is not about between what sets do you define $x \mapsto x^p$. But what is the meaning you give to $x^p$ when $p$ is not an integer?

Comment: For rational $p$ the proof can be given easily via multiplication with conjugates. For irrational $p$ you need to use the continuity of $\log/\exp$ functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the function $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence for $a \in \mathbb{R}^{*+}$, for all $\epsilon>0$, it exists $\eta>0$ so that $\left|x-a\right|<\eta$ implies $\left|e^{x}-e^{a}\right|<\epsilon$.

Then 
$$
\left|x^{p}-a^{p}\right|=\left|e^{p \ln\left(x\right)}-e^{p \ln\left(a\right)}\right|<\epsilon
$$

Comment: You left out a big piece of justification that $\ln(x)$ is continuous. So the proof should look like: by the continuity of $\ln(x)$, for each $\delta>0$, find $\eta >0$ so that $|x-a|<\eta$ implies $| \ln(x) - \ln(a) | < \delta$. Then by continuity of $e^z$, find $\epsilon >0$ so that $ |z-d|<\delta$ implies $|e^z - e^d |  <\epsilon $, then take $z= \ln(x)$ and $d=\ln(a)$.

Comment: The reciprocal of a continuous function is continuous no ? Or am i wrong ?

Comment: that’s true at points where the original function is nonzero, yes.

Comment: Where did you use the fact that "The reciprocal of a continuous function is continuous"? Or did you mean the inverse?

Comment: to say that $\ln$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{*+}$

Comment: Oh you meant inverse, not reciprocal.

Comment: Sorry, i made a transparent word with french. My bad then !

Answer (score 1):

A bit more:

For $x>0$, the function

a)$\exp(x)$, defined and continous on $\mathbb{R}$.

b) $\log(x)$, defined and continous on $\mathbb{R^+_{\star}}.$

Consider  $p>0$, given.

$f(x) = x^p := \exp(p\log(x)).$

$f$ being the composition of 2 continuous functions is continuous on $ \mathbb{R^+_{\star}}.$

The problem :

Show that $f(x)=x^p$ is continuous at $x= a >0.$

$\epsilon,$ $ \delta$ proof.

Plan:

1) Show that $p\log(x)$ is continous at $x=a.$

2) Show that $\exp(y)$ is continous at $y= p\log(a)$.

3) Along the lines of user layman's comment show that the composition of the $2$ functions is continuos.

Note :$\exp$ and $\log $ are base $e$ above.

Comments welcome.